# MVC6 unable to render the page

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I had just updated MVC 6 from beta7 to beta8. Now I am in strange situation. Everything works fine but when I execute the web application I see no output / rendered page.

Same thing works for beta7 but not for beta8. I checked Event Logging of the application I got following

> The description for Event ID 1001 from source HttpPlatformHandler cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local computer.
>
> If the event originated on another computer, the display information had to be saved with the event.
>
> The following information was included with the event:
>
> Process '14428' started successfully and is listening on port '30801'.

I had tried uninstall/re-install, update delete etc all the solutions I could have found from the internet but still I cannot render the page. Sample application is available at http://files.fm/u/ahqmkfn.

Please check that and do let me know if there is any configuration I am missing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Drop to cmd and run your website project directly via dnx;

```
cd /your/website/directory
dnx web
```

Open a browser to the listening port and the error will be displayed in the cmd window.  If your project doesn't build/run under dnx, run `dnvm list` and make sure the active version matches whatever version of aspnet your project is targeting.

Comment: Hi, I had already performed that but it still not working. Plus I removed all the directories for VS 2015 including registries, but some how I it is not working.

Finally I have to Format and re-install OS to make it work